# create a new column based on filter_at in R

Tags: r

I need to create a new yes/no (or 1/0) variable based on a group of existing ICD columns, whichever have specific values that meet the requirement.
My current code is:
inclusion %>% filter_at(vars("col1", "col2", "col3"), any_vars(. %in% c(49100, 49122, 48911, 404))). However, this will not help me generate the final yes/no variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use the `dplyr` function `dplyr::mutate()`. With this function you can add/modify columns in your dataset. You cannot do this with `dplyr::filter_at()`.

Comment: hi jing. Can you add a reprex? this will increase the chances of getting a concrete answer? (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `filter_at` you could consider using `mutate(across(...))` along with an `ifelse`:

```
inclusion %>%
   mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3),
   ~ifelse(.x %in% c(49100, 49122, 48911, 404), TRUE, FALSE)))
```

This would override those columns. If you want new columns add a `.names` argument as follows:

```
inclusion %>%
   mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3),
   ~ifelse(.x %in% c(49100, 49122, 48911, 404), TRUE, FALSE),
   .names = "{col}_in_vec"))
```

If you want to have a single output for whether any of the values are included in any of the three columns, use `c_across`:

```
inclusion %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(in_vec = any(c_across(c(col1, col2, col3)) %in% c(49100, 49122, 48911, 404)))
```

Comment: It should retain all observations, you can swap the `TRUE` `FALSE` for `1` and `0` if you prefer, but `mutate` won't drop observations.

Comment: All obs retained; but how can I find the new variable created? For example, if any of the three columns has a value of 49100, a new variable with value =1 is needed.

Comment: You need to ensure that you are (1) assigning the output to an object using `<-` and (2) in  `across` use the `.names` argument (as shown in the 2nd example) to create new columns with the desired output.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. Check the third solution and let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried exact code"inclusion %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(in_vec = any(c_across(c(col1, col2, col3)) %in% c(49100, 49122, 48911, 404)))" and this is the error message: Error: `c_across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: If I run it on `mtcars` it seems to work:
`mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(in_vec = any(c_across(c(mpg, cyl, disp)) %in% c(21, 6, 160)))`

You could instead pipe the result from the 2nd solution into another `mutate` which looks like `mutate(in_vec = ifelse(any(col1, col2, col3), 1, 0))`

Comment: Thank you very much - I will go back to the second solution

Comment: I just noticed if you're using the second solution make sure you use the new variable names, so it would be `mutate(in_vec = ifelse(any(col1_in_vec, col2_in_vec, col3_in_vec), 1, 0))`